# Yii2 - unique email with custom function

Tags: yii, yii2

Inside **rules** method I have this rules for email:

```
['email', 'uniqueEmail'],
['email', 'email'],
```

and uniqueEmail method:

```
public function uniqueEmail($attribute, $email)
    {
        $user = static::findOne(['email' => Yii::$app->encrypter->encrypt($email)]);
        if (count($user) > 0)
            $this->addError($attribute, 'This email is already in use".');
    }
```

Email validation is working, but **uniqueEmail** is not working. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that `$email` with be populated with that value? As stated by the docs, the second function param is actually parameters array, supplied at the end of the validator declaration (`['email', 'uninqueEmail', 'param1' => 'value1', 'param2', 'value2'])`

Try this:

```
public function uniqueEmail($attribute) {
    $user = static::findOne(['email' => Yii::$app->encrypter->encrypt($this->{$attribute})]);
    if ($user) { // dont use count($user) - if it's there, it's a single object, you want to check if it's not null!
        $this->addError($attribute, 'This email is already in use".');
    }
}
```

In `Yii2` it's accepted to declare ad-hoc validation as anonymous functions:

```
['email', function($attribute) {
    $user = static::findOne(['email' => Yii::$app->encrypter->encrypt($this->{$attribute})]);
    if ($user) {
        $this->addError($attribute, 'This email is already in use".');
    }
}],
['email', 'email'],
```

Comment: Tried your code (second method), but the validation is still not working :/

Comment: @Sasha please tell what do you mean by "not working". Do you have a record, in that table, that has `email` field with value same as the encrypted email you look up for? Do you get any errors, can you make a `var_dump($user); exit` in your validator? I just fixed one obvious issue, I can't guess how your database is modelled or how your application is expected to work.

Comment: There is a record with encrypted email in db. I must correct myself - the js part is not working (validation on the spot, without posting the form), but once that form is posted validation is working.

Comment: Validation by definition is only ran when you submit the form! This is what it does - it validates the submitted form. You should NOT expect it to run without submitting anything.

Comment: If you want client-side validation, you have to read this article: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#implementing-client-side-validation

Comment: Ok, but email validation is still working on the spot (without submitting the form).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81029/discussion-between-ddinchev-and-sasha).